# Getting attachments from http post request in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailgun

I'm using [Mailgun](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-receiving.html#supported-actions-for-routes) to receive emails for my web app developed using Codeigniter. Mailgun makes a http post to the following (http://something.com/email) url for every incoming email.

I get the contents of the email with the following code.

```
function email_to_db(){
   $email_body = $this->input->post('body-plain', '');
   $email_sender = $this->input->post('sender');
}
```

However I'm not able to fetch the attachments.
Can someone guide me on how I can achieve this. Following is the link to my reference doc.

Answer (score 0):

attachments are files, you should use [File Uploading Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

```
$config = [];
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']             = 100;
$config['max_width']            = 1024;
$config['max_height']           = 768;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
}
else
{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
}
```

you can also do `print_r($_FILES);` and check the attachment files.

Comment: I'm using Codeigniter with Google App Engine. I can't save files on the file system. I need to save them in the DB. Will the same code work fine?

Comment: hmm, not sure about that because of the "upload_path", I think you need to use $_FILES, you are getting a temporary position, and just upload from that position. you can also see what is the temp position and change upload path to that folder